# zipalign is working manually but failing under Jenkins post build

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins, amazon-ec2, post-build-event, zipalign

zipalign is working manually but failing under Jenkins post build. I am running it on Ubuntu Aws ec2 instance. Please can someone help me in figuring out the issue.

Jenkins Output :

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 14.421 secs
Built the following apk(s): 
    /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/PP_androidBuild/PatientPortal/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-debug.apk
[PP_androidBuild] $ echo '"resolving effective environment"'
[SignApksBuilder] searching environment variable ANDROID_HOME=/opt/android-sdk-linux for zipalign...
[SignApksBuilder] found zipalign in Android SDK's latest build tools: /opt/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/23.0.1/zipalign
[SignApksBuilder] /opt/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/23.0.1/zipalign -f -p 4 /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/PP_androidBuild/PatientPortal/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-debug.apk /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/PP_androidBuild/SignApksBuilder-out/zipalign/aligned-android-debug-6100835664895780913.apk
[PP_androidBuild] $ /opt/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/23.0.1/zipalign -f -p 4 /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/PP_androidBuild/PatientPortal/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-debug.apk /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/PP_androidBuild/SignApksBuilder-out/zipalign/aligned-android-debug-6100835664895780913.apk
FATAL: [SignApksBuilder] zipalign failed: exit code 1
ERROR: zipalign failed on APK /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/PP_androidBuild/PatientPortal/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-debug.apk: exit code 1
Finished: FAILURE
```

Output when I ran it in command prompt :

```
jenkins@ip-172-31-22-20:~$  /opt/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/23.0.1/zipalign -f -p 4 /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/PP_androidBuild/PatientPortal/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-debug.apk /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/PP_androidBuild/SignApksBuilder-out/zipalign/aligned-android-debug-6100835664895780913.apk
jenkins@ip-172-31-22-20:~$ ls -lthr /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/PP_androidBuild/SignApksBuilder-out/zipalign/aligned-android-debug-6100835664895780913.apk
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins jenkins 5.9M Sep  8 14:09 /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/PP_androidBuild/SignApksBuilder-out/zipalign/aligned-android-debug-6100835664895780913.apk
```

I further investigated and found that aligned-android-debug-6100835664895780913.apk is also created :

```
$ ls -lthr /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/PP_androidBuild/SignApksBuilder-out/zipalign/aligned-android-debug-6100835664895780913.apk | grep aligned-android-debug-6100835664895780913.apk
-rwxrwxrwx 1 jenkins jenkins 5.9M Sep  8 14:09 /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/PP_androidBuild/SignApksBuilder-out/zipalign/aligned-android-debug-6100835664895780913.apk
```

So what is the error ? How to find it and troubleshoot it ?

```
FATAL: [SignApksBuilder] zipalign failed: exit code 1
```

Comment: anybody has solution for this ?

Comment: Hi @Ashish Karpe, I'm facing the exact same issue on AWS Linux, but only with one of my projects. Other projects being signed with the same Jenkins agent work fine. So the fault is not with the agent nor the Android SDK build tools installation. It's the specific project. Have you found a solution to this?

Comment: @Mig82 I face this issue on some projects, It worked for my previous Jenkins  pipeline :) .......... still waiting for solution or hint :)

Comment: Anybody has solution

Answer (score 0):

> **The problem is because of the **generated key file****

**PROBLEM**

- I had generated the key file for release apk,
- But i had configured my jenkins build to generate debug apk in the invoke gradle section

[image: zipalign exit with code1]

**SOLUTION**

- Configure the jenkins build (As mentioned below) to generate signed
  release apk if you generate key file for release apk

[image: Gradle config]

- Once you configured the buid successfully, You will get the signed
  release apk

[image: Build success]